# How to Fill a Psvectorian Ornament with Color

Tags: xetex, color, pstricks, pspicture, psvectorian

I would like to be able to specify the fill color of a `psvectorian` image instead of having it filled with the background color.

For example, if I would like, say, to color the image of the bird outlined in white with `blue!35`, how may I do that?

[image]

The code which produced the above picture (and is compiled with `xelatex`) is ---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{pstricks,psvectorian}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(4,4)%
\psframe[fillcolor=brown!65!yellow,fillstyle=solid](-5,-5)(5,12) 
\psframe[linecolor=brown!42!black](-5,-5)(5,12)

% oiseau
\renewcommand*{\psvectorianDefaultColor}{white}%
\rput[tr]{-30}(-1.3,3.75){\psvectorian[width=2.1cm]{57}}
\end{pspicture}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

You could try an overlap with a very slight kern, perhaps.

[image: oiseau]

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{pstricks,psvectorian}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(4,4)%
\psframe[fillcolor=brown!65!yellow,fillstyle=solid](-5,-5)(5,12) 
\psframe[linecolor=brown!42!black](-5,-5)(5,12)

% oiseau
\renewcommand*{\psvectorianDefaultColor}{white}%
\rput[tr]{-30}(-1.3,3.75){\psvectorian[width=2.1cm,color=blue]{57}\kern0.35pt\llap{\psvectorian[width=2.1cm,color=red]{57}}
}
\end{pspicture}%
\end{document}
```

Detail:

[image: detail]

Answer (score 7):

For fun with [Asymptote](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/).

Run with `asy -f pdf <file name>.asy`.

Update

```
settings.tex="xelatex";
usepackage("pstricks");
usepackage("psvectorian");

path[] g=texpath("\psvectorian[width=2.1cm,color=blue]{57}");
pen[] colors={red, green, blue, orange, cyan, magenta, gray};
colors.cyclic=true;

picture pic;
size(pic,5cm);
for (int i=0; i<g.length; ++i)
 fill(pic,g[i],colors[i]);

frame f=rotate(-30)*align(pic.fit(),dir(-135));
add(f,(-1.3,3.75));
add(reflect((-1.3,3.75),(-1.3,3.75)+(0,0.1))*f,(-1.3,3.75));
dot(Label("$(-1.3,3.75)$"),(-1.3,3.75),N,Fill(red));

shipout(bbox(mm,Fill(0.35*brown+0.65*yellow+opacity(.7))));
```

[image]

```
settings.tex="xelatex";
usepackage("pstricks");
usepackage("psvectorian");
unitsize(1cm);

path[] g=texpath("\psvectorian[width=2.1cm,color=blue]{57}");
pen[] colors={red, green, blue, orange, cyan, magenta, gray};
colors.cyclic=true;

for (int i=0; i<g.length; ++i)
 filldraw(g[i],colors[i]);
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
\psvectorian[width=2.1cm,color=red]{57}
```

is the right way to change the line color. However, there is no fillcolor
because nearly all symbols have no closed curve!