# How to Produce a Vertical Kerning for a Psvectorian Image

Tags: xetex, pstricks, kerning, vertical, psvectorian

This post is an extension of [How to Fill a Psvectorian Ornament with Color](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/637859/how-to-fill-a-psvectorian-ornament-with-color/637908#637908)

The following code produces two images: the first with a horizontal kerning of 0.35pt; the second, with an attempted vertical "kerning" of -0.35pt. Alas, the second image turns out to be merely a duplication of the first.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{pstricks,psvectorian}
\usepackage{color}

% Compiles with XELATEX
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(4,4)%
\psframe[fillcolor=black,fillstyle=solid](-5,-5)(5,12) 
\psframe[linecolor=black](-5,-5)(5,12)

\rput[b](0,2){\psvectorian[width=8.1cm,color=brown!45!yellow]{69} \kern0.35pt\llap{\psvectorian[width=8.1cm,color=white]{69}}}

\rput[b](0,-3){\psvectorian[width=8.1cm,color=brown!45!yellow]{69} \vspace*{-.35pt}\llap{\psvectorian[width=8.1cm,color=white]{69}}}
\end{pspicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

It seems that for an image such as `psvectorian{69}` a slight negative vertical shift might be visually preferable over the slightly positive horizontal kerning in the first.
But I have not been able to effect such a vertical drop.

Does anyone know how I may produce a negative vertical kerning of 0.35pt (if I may use the term *kerning* for such a vertical shift) for the second image? Also, I do not know why the second image is a duplication of the first. (It seems to me that if the `\vspace{-0.35pt}` command was ignored, I might get simply the image given by `\psvectorian{69}` instead of the effect of `\kern0.35pt`.}

Comment: Most of your shift does not actually come from the `\kern` but from the space in front of `\kern` or `\vspace` which is present in both versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes no sense to use text macros inside a graphical environement. Use always `\rput`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{pstricks,psvectorian}
\usepackage{color}

% Compiles with XELATEX
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(4,4)%
\psframe[fillcolor=black,fillstyle=solid](-5,-5)(5,12) 
\psframe[linecolor=black](-5,-5)(5,12)

\rput[b](0,2){\psvectorian[width=8.1cm,color=brown!45!yellow]{69}} 
\rput[b](0.35pt,2){\psvectorian[width=8.1cm,color=white]{69}}

\rput[b](0,-3){\psvectorian[width=8.1cm,color=brown!45!yellow]{69}} 
\rput[b](0,\dimexpr-3cm-0.35pt){\psvectorian[width=8.1cm,color=white]{69}}
\end{pspicture}%
\end{document}
```