# How to Produce a Bold Psvectorian Image

Tags: graphics, xetex, pstricks, bold, psvectorian

This MWE code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{pstricks,psvectorian}
\usepackage{color}

% Compiles with XELATEX
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(4,4)%
\psframe[fillcolor=red!65!black,fillstyle=solid](-5,-5)(5,12) 
\psframe[linecolor=red!65!black](-5,-5)(5,12)

% oiseaux
\rput[tr]{-30}(-1.3,3){\psvectorian[width=2.1cm,color=white]{57}}

\bfseries %But---THIS DOES NOT appear to make the following image bold.
\rput[tr]{-30}(-1.3,1){\psvectorian[width=2.1cm,color=white]{57}}
\end{pspicture}%
\end{document}
```

produces the following

[image]

I have attempted to make the second image bold by use of the `\bfseries` command, but as you can see---it does not appear to effect the desired outcome. (Incidentally, `\textbf` produced an error, which is probably not surprising.)

How may I invoke a `psvectorian` image and have it displayed more prominently (i.e., in bold) than that which is produced, in this case, by `\psvectorian{57}`?

Comment: `\bfseries` is for text, while this is a drawing, so the command does not modify the drawing in any way. Postscript (the language used to make the drawings) does have a line width parameter, however the vectorian images are not drawn as lines but as filled curves, which do not have a line width either. So the only thing you can do is to either overprint the image with a small offset (put the figure two times, at `(-1.3,3)` and at `(-1.3,3.02)` for example) which does not look very nice, or add emphasis using a different color or a different size.

Comment: `contour` package gives the effect of bolder if the same colour is used; or `\llap` with an offset. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27843/level-of-boldness-changeable/27845#27845

Comment: Correction: `contour` package works on fonts, not PostScript commands. A possible `\llap` solution is given in the answer, but results detract from the image's design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{pstricks,psvectorian}

\makeatletter
\def\psBoldVectorian{\@ifnextchar[\psBoldVectorian@i{\psBoldVectorian@i[]}}
\def\psBoldVectorian@i[#1]#2{%
  \rput(0,0){\psvectorian[#1]{#2}}%
  \rput(0.4pt,0.4pt){\psvectorian[#1]{#2}}%
  \rput(-0.4pt,-0.4pt){\psvectorian[#1]{#2}}%
}
\makeatother
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(4,4)%
\psframe[fillcolor=red!65!black,fillstyle=solid](-5,-5)(5,12) 
\psframe[linecolor=red!65!black](-5,-5)(5,12)

% oiseaux
\rput{-30}(-1.3,3){\psvectorian[width=2.1cm,color=white]{57}}
\rput{-30}(-1.3,1){\psBoldVectorian[width=2.1cm,color=white]{57}}
\end{pspicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A kind of fake bold can be simulated by putting the drawing twice, here with an overlap in the same colour, plus a small kern, and very slightly larger width.

[image: fake bold]

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{pstricks,psvectorian}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% Compiles with XELATEX
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(4,4)%
\psframe[fillcolor=red!65!black,fillstyle=solid](-5,-5)(5,12) 
\psframe[linecolor=red!65!black](-5,-5)(5,12)

% oiseaux
\rput[tr]{-30}(-1.3,3){\psvectorian[width=2.1cm,color=white]{57}}

\rput[tr]{-30}(-1.3,1){\psvectorian[width=2.1cm,color=white]{57}\kern0.45pt\llap{\psvectorian[width=2.12cm,color=white]{57}}}
\end{pspicture}%
\end{document}
```

A two-colour solution is at: [How to Fill a Psvectorian Ornament with Color](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/637859/how-to-fill-a-psvectorian-ornament-with-color/637894#637894)

---

The drawing is designed to emulate fine penmanship, so black strokes on white background, and no further emphasis is required.

[image: bw]

Altering the composition's design breaks the fine detail.